# True Crypt потерян ключевой файл

Tags: безопасность, windows-10, пароль, музыка, брутфорс

Есть раздел в другом разделе (от первого пароль помню и от второго тоже), второй где-то на гигабайт. На нём файл docx размером в 23 кб. Это план по проекту. Всё было бы хорошо, но однажды я решил переустановить винду. Была и осталась десятка LTSC, и во время переустановки я забыл про ключевой файл. Я знаю, что это была песня 3 Doors Down Kryptonite, скачанная с Яндекс Музыки в середине-конце февраля. После переустановки я столкнулся с тем, что том не монтируется, и скачал новый Kryptonite, но он не подошёл. Я рекувой достал старый, но он тоже не подошёл, достал ещё другой, платной программой, и опять. Могу выслать том на почту. Если что не ясно - спрашивайте.
Что делать? 
P.S. да, я уже пытался восстановить проект по памяти. Хреново получилось.
P.P.S. Почему никто не отвечает? Я выбрал не тот форум?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не по теме сайта.

Comment: А на какой форум тогда отправлять?

Comment: На форум техподдержки какой-нибудь. А скорее всего, никто вам не поможет. Ищите именно тот самый файл, другой mp3 не подойдёт, неважно что для той же песни.